# Spring data JPA repository saveAll is not generating bulk insert query

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data 2.2.8 and hibernate 5.4.17.Final versions. and database is oracle 11g
when I am saving the data with repository.saveAll(list) it is not generating bulk insert query.
it is generating a single query for each record.

below is entity sequence related info

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PAYG_RECONCILIATION_IDS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PAYG_RECONCILIATION_IDS", sequenceName = "PAYG_RECONCILIATION_IDS")
@Column
private Long paygReconciliationId;
```

bellow is the saving the entities code

```
paygReconciliationRepository.saveAll(paygReconciliationMap.values());
```

bellow are hibernate settings

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.cubic.cts.core.persistence.main.dto", "com.cubic.frm.persistence.main.dto");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 50);
    properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}
```

after flushing one batch below are the queries generated

```
Hibernate: insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

below are the hibernate stats

```
    2021-07-13 13:15:26,261 [INFO ] scheduler_Worker-1 StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    466400 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    867200 nanoseconds spent preparing 13 JDBC statements;
    7763800 nanoseconds spent executing 11 JDBC statements;
    51541800 nanoseconds spent executing 8 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    4921200 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 400 entities and 400 collections);
    214407100 nanoseconds spent executing 7 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 2200 entities and 2200 collections)
}
```

in the above stat 7763800 to execute the 13 JDBC statements and again it has 51541800 executing 8 JDBC batches. i think if we can make hibernate to prepaer single insert query for all records we can archive some performance

is there any possibility to make single batch insert query for multiple records? below is the exaple query, that i am trying to archive

```
insert into payg_reconciliation (version, inserted_dtm, bc_pay_sale_txn_payment_id, bc_pay_amount, bc_pay_cch_settlement_date, last_source_updated_dtm, merchant_id, payg_recon_status_id, bankcard_payment_id, declined_flag, subsystem_enum, retrieval_ref_nbr, payg_reconciliation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

why hibernate is not generating single insert query, did i miss anything in my settings?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Set below properties in application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=4
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

The first property tells Hibernate to collect inserts in batches of four. The order_inserts property tells Hibernate to take the time to group inserts by entity, creating larger batches.

Comment: you can see those settings in the above question,  I have already added in hibernate properties, adding in application.properties, or in LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean are same

Comment: @GaaliPrabhakar your batch size is 50 and it has executed 8 batches and 400 entities are saved. what else are you expecting.
 it is properly executing the things in batches

Comment: More over what query you are expecting to be logged and normal query sent for 50 entities are same and will have same performance. And what else is logged in the console?
Here for your entity id sequence also there are queries sent to DB - consider that as well

Comment: batch is 50 only and in that session, I am updating 50 "sales" entites and inserting new 50 "recon", then batch size should be 2, but how it is 8 batches, is there any way that, can I see those batch details?, and DB and in entity sequence allocation size is 50

Comment: see as per that log it saved 400 entities in first flush and 2200 in 7 partial flushes.
If you want to check only this saveAll() performance, test with only saveAll with some big data.
More over you can log the query and count of batch size using interceptor as given in 
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

Comment: but Hibernate preparing the query for each record even record in batch, which is not usefull and taking time, if I can remove multiple queries generation for a batch, then I can save some time